# webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin is not a constructor

Tags: webpack, travis-ci, webpack-3

Getting the following error on Travis CI since upgrading to Webpack 3.

It seems to work fine on my local environment, but when I commit to master and kick of Travis it keeps failing now with the following error.

```
21 06 2017 20:16:31.514:ERROR [config]: Invalid config file!
  TypeError: webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/travis/build/.../webpack.prod.config.babel.js:91:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at loader (/home/travis/build/.../node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/travis/build/.../node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
```

And the Line it's complaining about

```
// Webpack 3 Scope Hoisting
new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
```

And also have set Webpack to version 3 in my `package.json` of course.

```
"webpack": "^3.0.0",
```

And my Travis `yml` is pretty simple

```
language: node_js
sudo: false
node_js:
- '8'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` then run `npm install` again to generate a new `package-lock.json`. Once you commit the new `package-lock.json`, Travis should work correctly.

I was having the exact same issue locally, I did what I described and I stopped having that issue.

Comment: I tried deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling again, but it was failing. Also deleting `package-lock.json` solved the issue for me.